# Tab key cause position change and overflow hidden elements comes to screen

Tags: html, css, tabs, html.hiddenfor

[image]

Here is a step by step form working as a slider.

Parent div has styling

```
#formContainer {
position: absolute;
top: calc((100% - 400px) / 2);
overflow: hidden;
}
```

and children has

```
.step {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

active child has

```
.step-1 .select {
    left: 0;
}
```

passive childs has

```
.step-1 .mail, .step-1 .add-message, .step-1 .progress, .step-1 .complete {
    left: 600px;
}
```

When first step is active and pressing TAB key, it looks like:

[image]

Somehow, even though hidden steps left is set to 600px, positioning conflicts and other steps elems comes into screen.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `visibility: hidden` to hidden elems solve unwanted scrolling and slide effect remains.

```
.step-1 .mail, .step-1 .add-message, .step-1 .progress, .step-1 .complete {
    left: 600px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```